# Select records not in another table with additional criteria

Tags: sql, select

I am working on an ACCESS DB.

I have 1 table (tblData) with 1 column ( DataId) and 3 entries:

```
tblData (A)
+--------+
| DataId |
+--------+
|   1    | 
|   2    |
|   3    |
+--------+
```

Another table (tblSelections) contains 3 columns (id, dataid, userid) and has 3 entries:

```
tblSelections (B)
+----+--------+---------+
| id | dataid | userid  |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 | 1      | 5       |
|  2 | 2      | 5       |
|  3 | 3      | 2       |
+----+--------+---------+
```

How can I select the records from table A (tblData) which are not in tbl B (tblSelections) for a certain 'userid'?

For 'userid' 5 the query must return 'DataId' 3 from table A as dataid 1 & 2 are already present in table B for userid 5.

For 'userid' 2 the query must return 'DataId' 1 & 2 from table A as dataid 3 is already present in table B for userid 2.

For 'userid' 1 the query must return 'DataId' 1, 2 & 3 from table A as no records are present in table B for userid 1

Answer (score 1):

Use EXISTS or IN for queries like yours:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblData 
WHERE DataId NOT IN
(
  SELECT dataid 
  FROM tblSelections 
  WHERE userid = 5
);

SELECT * 
FROM tblData 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM tblSelections 
  WHERE tblSelections.dataid = tblData.DataId AND tblSelections.userid = 5
);
```

Comment: Just FYI, while the first query will work in this *particular* case, it isn't a general-purpose solution (since it will only work in cases where there is a single matching column).

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot about this. I am used to using WHERE (a,b,c) IN ..., but this is because I work with Oracle. This feature may not be available in other dbms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an outer join to select all records, then put a condition in the `where` clause that a non-nullable column in `b` is `null`. This will give you all records in `a` that do not have a matching row in `b` according to the join conditions.

This query assumes that you have a parameter or variable named `@userid` that represents the user ID to search against.

```
select
    a.*

from tblData a

left join tblSelections b on b.dataid = a.dataid and b.userid = @userid

where b.id is null
```

Comment: there is no column like userid in tblData

Comment: @VigneshKumar: No, but there is one in `tblSelections`

Comment: Yes first you have used tblData  as b that's why i said

Comment: @VigneshKumar: I think you might have misread; the query hasn't changed since I posted it.

Comment: I am here only. and i got that you updated your answer. dont say me misread and all